# At what points in a program the system switch threads

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

I know that threads cannot actually run in parallel **on the same core**, but in a regular desktop system there is normally hundreds or even thousands of threads. Which is of course much more than today's average of 4 core CPU's. So the system actually running some thread for X time and then switches to run another thread for Y amount of time an so on.

My question is, how does the system decide how much time to execute each thread?

I know that when a program is calling `sleep()` on a thread for an amount of time, the operation system can use this time to execute other threads, but what happens when a program does not call sleep at all?

E.g:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    while(true)
        printf("busy");

    return 0;
}
```

When does the operating system decide to suspend this thread and excutre another?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)

Comment: They can run on the same core. The technology is called [hyper-threading](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS keeps a container of all those threads that can use CPU execution, (usually such threads are described as being'ready').  On most desktop systems, this is a very small fraction of the total number of threads.  Most threads in such systems are waiting on either I/O, (this includes sleeping - waiting on timer I/O), or inter-thread signaling; such threads cannot use CPU execution and so the OS does not dispatch them onto cores.

A software syscall, (eg. a request to open a file, a request to sleep or wait for a signal from another thread), or a hardware interrupt from a peripheral device, (eg. a disk controller, NIC, KB, mouse), may cause the set of ready threads to change and so initiate a scheduling run.

When run, the shceduler decides on what set of ready threads to assign to the available cores.  The algorithm it uses is a compromise that tries to optimize overall performance by balancing the need for expensive context-switches with the need for responsive I/O.  The kernel CAN stop any thread on any core an preempt it, but it would surely prefer not to:)

So:

> My question is, how does the system decide how much time to execute
>   each thread?

Essentially, it does not.  If the set of ready threads is not greater than the number of cores, there is no need to stop/control/influence a CPU-intensive loop - it can be allowed to run on forever, taking up a whole core.

Note that your example is very poor - the printf() call will request output from the OS and, if not immediately available, the OS will block your seemingly 'CPU only' thread until it is.

> but what happens when a program does not call sleep at all?

It's just one more thread.  If it is purely CPU-intensive, then whether it runs continually depends upon the loading on the box and the number of cores available, as already described.  It can, of course, get blocked by requesting I/O or electing to wait for a signal from another thread, so removing itself from the set of ready threads.

Note that one I/O device is a hardware timer. This is very useful for timing out system calls and providing Sleep() functionality.  It usually does have a side-effect on those boxes where the number of ready threads is larger than the number of cores available to run them, (ie. the box is overloaded or the task/s it runs have no limits on CPU use).  It can result in sharing out the available cores around the ready threads, so giving the illusion of running more threads than it's actually physically capable of, (try not to get hung up on Sleep() and the timer interrupt - it's one of many interrupts that can change thread state).

It is this behaviour of the timer hardware, interrupt and driver that gives rise to the apalling 'quantum', 'time-sharing', 'round-robin' etc. etc.etc. confusion and FUD that surrounds the operation of modern preemptive kernels.

A preemptive kernel, and it's drivers etc, is a state-machine.  Syscalls from running threads and hardware interrupts from peripheral devices go in, a set of running threads comes out.

Answer (score 2):

It depends which type of scheduling your OS is using for example lets take

### **Round Robbin:**

In order to schedule processes fairly, a round-robin scheduler generally employs time-sharing, giving each job a time slot or quantum(its allowance of CPU time), and interrupting the job if it is not completed by then. The job is resumed next time a time slot is assigned to that process. If the process terminates or changes its state to waiting during its attributed time quantum, the scheduler selects the first process in the ready queue to execute.

There are others scheduling algorithms as well you will find this link useful:https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/5_CPU_Scheduling.html

Answer (score 2):

The operating system has a component called the scheduler that decides which thread should run and for how long. There are essentially two basic kinds of schedulers: [cooperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking) and [preemptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29). Cooperative scheduling requires that the threads cooperate and regularly hand control back to the operating system, for example by doing some kind of IO. Most modern operating systems use preemptive scheduling.

In preemptive scheduling the operating system gives a time slice for the thread to run. The OS does this by setting a handler for a CPU timer: the CPU regularly runs a piece of code (the scheduler) that checks if the current thread's time slice is over, and possibly decides to give the next time slice to a thread that is waiting to run. The size of the time slice and how to choose the next thread depends on the operating system and the scheduling algorithm you use. When the OS switches to a new thread it saves the state of the CPU (register contents, program counter etc) for the current thread into main memory, and restores the state of the new thread - this is called a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

If you want to know more, the Wikipedia article on [Scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) has lots of information and pointers to related topics.